# Pagination for Seeded Random List

Tags: python

I need to generate a list of data.  The data is randomised based on a seed.  As the list has potentially no limit to size, I am thinking of using pagination to send the data back to requester.  The list has to be replicable with a given seed by requester.

Unlike getting data from a database where I can specify offset and number of records to retrieve, the random list needs to be created each time ?  How do I avoid having to start from the beginning to get to the nth page (for instance) ?  eg

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
for i in range(20):
    print(f'{i+1}\t=\t{np.random.randint(100)}')

1   =   44
2   =   47
3   =   64
4   =   67
5   =   67
6   =   9
7   =   83
8   =   21
9   =   36
10  =   87
11  =   70
12  =   88
13  =   88
14  =   12
15  =   58
16  =   65
17  =   39
18  =   87
19  =   46
20  =   88
```

I my page size = 10, how to avoid generating 1-10 by the time I'm generating 11-20 for the 2nd page ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're writing this program in C#, it would be helpful to see what you've tried so far in that language. The python doesn't seem very relevant.

Comment: Ok if there is a python answer.  I can implement in python also.  I've remove the c#.  Let this be a python question.

Comment: I think what you're asking for is fundamentally impossible. That's not how random number algorithms work.

Comment: how big is "potentially limitless"? Generating a million random numbers takes only a couple of ms, and this would only be required once and then can be used as a constant.